# How to get page numbers based on id

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting

My website currently pulls my content based on rowid, however it gives it a page number based on DESC order. This is ok to some, however when I add a new article to my website and someone clicks the next button it can sometimes take them to the same page if I add new page within the time they clicked the next button.

```
    $limit = 1;  
    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
    $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
```

I still want the last entry in my database (highest row id) to be displayed. Curious what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Print the `$sql` and check the query

Comment: I would suggest using a separate page number field. If your page numbers are part of the url, and someone book marks a page, their bookmark will be invalid.

Comment: It works the way it is, but since it sorts them by descending order it assigns page id incremented. So say my last entry was row id 56, the page number would not be 56, it would be 1.

Comment: Exactly @SloanThrasher that's what I am trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: If your query were based on page number instead of a relative value based on the highest page number (in essence what you currently have), then page numbers would be stable. However, if a user is on the last page number, they wouldn't have a next until the page was refreshed. A much smaller problem, and one that wouldn't confuse users.

Comment: So add a column for page number. Then your select is simple, just match the requested page number against that field.

Comment: So I add a column for page number, then in the admin panel I edit the submit code to add the page number into it, but check for the last page number and then +1 and then just change the order by id to pageid... Why didn't I think of that. Thanks a bunch @SloanThrasher

Comment: @SloanThrasher I changed my code on the backend, but I'm not sure where to begin on displaying my results using my existing code.

Comment: It should be really simple. Instead of getting the page based on relative distance from last page (like you are doing), you simply match the actual page number given from the page.

Comment: You're right, I was over thinking it haha. Thanks again!

Comment: $pageid = $_GET["page"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE pageid=$pageid";

This works perfect! However how can I make it so on the index page it detects the most recently added row and pulls that pageid and orders them in descending order, because my previous and next buttons are now reversed haha!
@SloanThrasher

Basically the pageid is 9999999 and every submission subtracts 1. I want it to load the newest first which would be 9999998

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This makes it so when the user visits your index.php page it redirects them to the newest post. I added a table for pageid and set it at 9999999999. I doubt I could post that much content.

```
<?php
$rowcountprep = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles");  
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($rowcountprep); 
if (!$_GET["page"])
{
$total = '10000000000';
$current = $total-$rowcount;
?>
<script>window.location="example.com/index.php?page=<?php echo 
$current; ?>"</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks to @SloanThrasher for the help.