# How to echo result from query

Tags: php, mysqli

Maybe I am overthinking this, but I have narrowed my query to find a row down to 1 result that I need, and it will not display. Wondering if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT pageid FROM article ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_use_result($result);

echo $row;
```

I have it selecting the last row and supplying me with the stored data from the pageid of the last row.

Comment: Fetch the result.

Comment: which api did you connect with? your last question shows as `mysql_` http://stackoverflow.com/q/43359978/1415724 - Plus, the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php states to use `while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }` for example. And also states *"Used to initiate the retrieval of a result set from the last query executed using the mysqli_real_query() function on the database connection."* - which you are not using that function.

Comment: $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

Answer (score 1):

I had to adapt my code. I believe it was because I use mysql. However, this code will work if you use mysqli

```
$pageid = "SELECT pageid FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultpageid = $link->query($pageid);

if ($resultpageid->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resultpageid->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pagenumber = $row["pageid"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli doesn't have any function to get a single column from a single row. You need to use one of the fetch methods e.g. [`fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). You don't need any loop if you use `LIMIT 1`.

Just fetch a single row and get the column from the returned array:

```
$pageid = "SELECT pageid FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultpageid = $link->query($pageid);

$row = $resultpageid->fetch_assoc();
// or
$row = $resultpageid->fetch_array();

if ($row) {
    echo $row["pageid"];
} else {
    echo "No record found!";
}
```